# how to fix scrapy source code test failure: FifoDiskQueue

Tags: python, unit-testing, scrapy

After downloading the source code of Scrapy 0.16, I tried to run the tests using ./bin/runtests.sh on my Macbook. Surprisingly, the test failed. It gives these results:FAILED (skips=46, failures=9, successes=887).
Has any of you guys encountered this problem? How do you fix it?

```
[FAIL]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lws/Downloads/scrapy-scrapy-7b5310d/scrapy/tests/test_utils_queue.py", line 128, in test_close_open
    self.assertEqual(q.pop(), 'c')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/trial/unittest.py", line 270, in assertEqual
    % (msg, pformat(first), pformat(second)))
twisted.trial.unittest.FailTest: not equal:
a = None
b = 'c'

[FAIL]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lws/Downloads/scrapy-scrapy-7b5310d/scrapy/tests/test_utils_queue.py", line 128, in test_close_open
    self.assertEqual(q.pop(), 'c')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/trial/unittest.py", line 270, in assertEqual
    % (msg, pformat(first), pformat(second)))
twisted.trial.unittest.FailTest: not equal:
a = 'e'
b = 'c'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug in scrapy which does not seem to manifest itself on GNU/Linux, only on mac os. It is caused by the fact that FifoDiskQueue mixes unbuffered file reading with buffered file seek.

I've written a [PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/201) which addresses this and some other compatibility issues found. Not sure when the fixes will make it into a new release though.

Scrapy does work without problems on mac os though (FifoDiskQueue is an alternative queue mechanism not used by default).

Comment: The pull request is merged now.